# Android App - Listen for calls in Hangouts Dialer

Tags: android, listener, google-hangouts

Is there a way to create an app that listens for calls that come in through the Google Hangouts and Hangouts Dialer Apps? I know there's an API for Hangouts Apps, but I'd rather create a standalone app that detects events from Hangouts and Hangouts Dialer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could tell there is no Hangouts API for android, just the web app.